# jqGrid saving a date back to the server

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date, jqgrid-formatter

I'm working with a jqGrid and have a column with a date field in my model:

```
colModel: [
  ...
  { name: 'dayin', 
    label: 'Day In', 
    formatter: 'date', 
    formatoptions:{newformat:"m/d/Y"},
    editable: true
  },
  ...
]
```

I have not modified the `grid.local-en.js` file so the default `srcFormat` is `Y-m-d` and the default `newFormat` is `m/d/Y`.  From the server I'm getting dates in the standard `Y-m-d` format from MySQL.  As expected, they display as `m/d/Y` in the grid and when editing.

The problem is when I go to save the row, it goes back to the server as the `m/d/Y` format instead of getting converted back to the default `srcFormat` of `Y-m-d`.  I had assumed that the formatter `'date'` feature would automatically handle the conversion back to the `srcFormat` on an inline or form save.  I have tried changing the newformat to `Y-m-d` which correctly sends the date fields back and forth, but it's not how I want to display it to the user.

Most of the examples I have found so far only deal with getting the information from the server onto the screen - can someone point me to an example that shows how to get the date back to the server in `Y-m-d` when it is displayed as `m/d/Y` in the grid?

I'm sure I can force this in several places, but it seems like there should be an easy technique to make this happen.  I thought the code would call the unformatter function (line 5298) but this doesn't appear to get executed as part of the submit flow.

I'm using jqGrid 4.3.0, jQuery-1.6.2, and jquery-ui-1.8.16 in case this is a known feature I overlooked in this particular version.  I was trying to do this originally with a datepicker, but this is a simpler case.  I think adding in the datepicker will be pretty simple once I get past this point.